# Microstrategy intelligent cube data aggragation

Tags: report, reporting, microstrategy

I created a cube that contain five attributes and a metric and I want to create a document from this cube with different visualisations for each attribute. the problem is that data in the cube are aggregated based on all attributes in the cube, so when you add a grid with one attribute and the metric the numbers will not be correct.
Is there any way to make the metric dynamically aggragate depending on the attribute in use?

Comment: Can you show some data and why the results are not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends what kind of metric you have in the cube. The best way to achieve aggregation across all attributes is obviously to have the most granular, least aggregated data in the cube, but understandably this is not always possible.

If your metric is a simple SUM metric then you can set your dynamic aggregation settings on the metric to just do SUM and it should perform SUM's appropriately regardless of the attributes you are placing on your document/report? Unless your attribute relationships are not set up correctly or there are some many-to-many relationships taking place between some of those attributes.

If you metric is a distinct count metric, then the approach is slightly different and has been covered previously in a few places. Here is one, on an older version of Microstrategy but the logic can still be applied to newer versions.:
http://community.microstrategy.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/architect/article-id/1695